# Making a box grow with JavaScript, then text appearing inside, using a function and InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, function, innerhtml

I'm learning JavaScript right now, and I've been playing with some neat things.
I've managed to write a function that makes a  box grow. For the past half hour I've been trying to get some text in the box after it grows.

I tried using the method InnerHTML, but no matter where I put it (I know I'm referencing the right element) no text appears (the colors are all right, not an invisible color issue).

What's even stranger is that if I use InnerHTML to put HTML in, the box doesn't grow at all. For example, I tried putting in `target.InnerHTML = "<p style="text-align:center"> It is <b> Done </b><p>";` and the box wouldn't grow on button click.

So the two things I'd like to know is how do I make text appear in the box after it grows and why won't it grow if I put HTML in?

```
<html>

    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        body {
            color: blue;
            width: 300px;
        }
        #a{ 
            color: green;
            padding: 10pt;
            background-color: blue;
            height: 200;
        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var newSetting = 200;
        function growLonger(element){
            target = document.getElementById(element);
            target.style.height = newSetting;
            target.style.width = newSetting;
            newSetting = newSetting +20;

            if (newSetting == 500){
                clearTimeout(loopTimer);
                return false;
            }
            var loopTimer = setTimeout('growLonger(\''+element+'\')',50);
                target.InnerHTML = "<p style="text-align:center"> It is <b> Done </b><p>";
        }
        </script>
        <title>"Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <p>Hi How are you?</p>
    <button onclick="growLonger('a')"> Grow Height </button>
    <div id="a">More text?</div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
target.InnerHTML = "<p style="text-align:center"> It is <b> Done </b><p>";
```

**innerHTML is innerHTML and not InnerHTML(camel casing)**

This should work:

```
target.innerHTML = "...";
```